# Redux with redux saga/redux thunk. Why some people says I shouldnt use thunk now because theres a saga

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

Im learning redux middleware, saga and thunknspecifically and I'm kinda confuse on why theres two exisiting middleware if they doing the same and benefiting your app. And I read some in the blog/post that saga much good compared to thunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an "apples and oranges" question.

Redux-Saga is an async side effects addon for the Redux core state management library.  You can use Redux by itself, or Redux-Saga with Redux, but this is *not* an "A or B" choice - they don't do the same thing at all.

Comment: Thank you for answering this! I keep an eye to this